# Minishift: Problems creating virtual machine

Tags: openshift-origin, minishift

my question about the installation of openshift environment using minishift on virtual box.

```
minishift v1.4.1+0f658ea
```

`VirtualBox-5.1.26-117224-Win.exe`

The installation is incomplete due to the folowing error:-

```
C:\Users\xyzdgs\Desktop\Openshift_n_Docker\OpenShift Developer>minishift.exe start --vm-driver=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxSVC.exe

-- Starting local OpenShift cluster using 'C:\Program' hypervisor ...
-- Minishift VM will be configured with ...
Memory:    2 GB
vCPUs :    2
Disk size: 20 GB
Downloading ISO 'https://github.com/minishift/minishift-b2d-iso/releases/download/v1.1.0/minishift-b2d.iso'
40.00 MiB / 40.00 MiB [===========================================] 100.00% 0s
-- Starting Minishift VM ... | Unsupported driver: C:\Program
```

So, to solve this I simply put the directory where all drivers are located in the installation and run it again

```
C:\Users\xyzdgs\Desktop\Openshift_n_Docker\OpenShift Developer>minishift.exe start --vm-driver=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\

-- Starting local OpenShift cluster using 'C:\Program' hypervisor ...
-- Starting Minishift VM ... / FAIL E0825 11:20:43.830638    1260 start.go:342]
Error starting the VM: Error getting the state for host: machine does not exist.
Retrying.
| FAIL E0825 11:20:44.297638    1260 start.go:342] Error starting the VM: Error getting the state for host: machine does not exist. Retrying.
/ FAIL E0825 11:20:44.612638    1260 start.go:342] Error starting the VM: Error getting the state for host: . Retrying.
Error starting the VM: Error getting the state for host: machine does not exist
Error getting the state for host: machine does not exist
Error getting the state for host: machine does not exist
```

It says "machine does not exist", shouldn't the machine be created by minishift itself (see te procedure here: blog.novatec-gmbh.de/getting-started-minishift-openshift-origin-one-vm/)

Not sure what is causing this. Please guide.

Comment: I think that you should ask this question at super user.

Comment: @ErAB, is this still an issue for you?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with the command -- and what it's *really* complaining about -- is that you're passing in an unquoted path:

`minishift.exe start --vm-driver=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxSVC.exe`

should have been

`minishift.exe start --vm-driver="C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxSVC.exe"`

**But according to the [MiniShift documentation](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/minishift/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-driver-plugins.html#machine-doesnt-exist)**, you should update to VirtualBox 5.1.12+ (which you have) and use the following syntax:

`minishift.exe start --vm-driver=virtualbox`

7 months after this question was asked and using VirtualBox v4.3.30, I can get MiniShift v1.15.1 running with the last command, but can't get it to accept your previous syntax or even produce the same error from it.